# Magento 2 : Make Wish-list functionality without Login (Guest Wish-list)

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I want to make a customization to add wishlist for guest, no need to install separately extension.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: no still not find any solution @MohitKumarArora